# Indian income tax 2014-2015

Tags: income-tax, india

I am filing my 2014-2015 Indian income taxes. I am outside India since Jan 2013 and currently in USA.
I am filing taxes using prepare and submit online ITR using ITR 1.
What should be my resident status? Resident, NRI or NOR for year 2014-2015?
What address shall I mention in personal  information  my USA address or Indian address?
Is there any thing else important that I need to consider?
please advise

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should be my resident status?

Based on above you have spent more than 182 days outside of India in the financial year 2014-2015. Hence you would be classified as "Non-Resident" [NRI]

> What address shall I mention in personal information my USA address or Indian address?

Your convenience, any correspondence from Income Tax, i.e. correction request, demand letter etc are sent to this address else its not used if things are correct. These days an email copy is also sent.

> Is there any thing else important that I need to consider?

Nope just ensure that you report all your Indian income, i.e. income from Interest on FD's or rent received etc and pay appropriate taxes. Otherwise its same as filing as Resident.

The key thing to remember is if you don't have digital signature, you would have to take a print out of ITR V after submitting online. You have to sign this in Blue Ink and post it to the address mentioned within 120 days. Best send it over to someone in India and they send it by Speed Post. Note the address is a PO Box so only ordinary letter are allowed, a special exception is made to Speed Post. Private courier will not be able to deliver to PO Box.

Comment: Thanks Dheer. I believe the FD interest and TDS is automatically pulled from PAN and shown in the TDS section. or do we need to get this information from bank and fill it in some sections? please specify the section if you are aware of it.

Comment: Also I have already uploaded my return with Resident status. Shall I create another one with NRI status? Is it possible to delete the previous upload?

Comment: Yes, it's automatically pulled for FD if you have given PAN details at the time of booking. Savings Interest is not shown. My suggestion is to file an amendment / revision with correct status